# Redirect loop in nginx with ssl and proxy to a second server

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have two servers server1.abc.com and server2.abc.com. I need a setup where all requests to server1.abc.com/c/'anything' get proxied to a second server, all other requests served locally from the first server. I have it all working without SSL with simple configuration of nginx on server1:

location  ~ .*/c/.* {
    proxy_pass  http://server2.ccloop.com;
  }

Now I need to switch server1 to SSL, but I can have content from server2 served in clear or SSL, it does not matter. I made no changes to nginx config and tried it. No problem serving SSL traffic from server1, however proxying to server2 does not work - nginx on server1 goes into infinite redirect loop and nothing shows up in access logs on server2?

What am I missing here?